# Selecting row using global variable

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I am opening a form and trying to fill it with data using a query that contains a global variable. This causes an alert box to pop up, prompting me to fill it with a value because the syntax is wrong somehow obviously. The table is staff and currentStaffMember is the global variable. This code is in a query.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Staff
WHERE EmployeeID = currentStaffMember;
```

https://imagebin.ca/v/3Z7LERXZNvnk (image showing record source)

https://imagebin.ca/v/3Z7Lhn9BnJzl (image showing query)

Comment: Can you add the code creating the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use global variables set in VBA in normal queries.

You can, however, use `TempVars` for exactly that purpose.

Set a `TempVar`: `TempVars!currentStaffMember = "John Doe"`

Use a `TempVar` in a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Staff
WHERE EmployeeID = Tempvars!currentStaffMember;
```